# How to get the path of config status for (ifconfig=" ") xml - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, local.xml, ifconfig

I want to know how we get the path of a config status for a natif and a custom module.

Assuming that i want to get a config path of:

> 1) System>Configuration>Design>View demo store warning message>
>   **No**.
>
> 2) System>Configuration>Web>Add store code to URLs> **Yes**.
>
> 3) System>Configuration>CustomModule>CustomField> **1**.

My layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layoutupdate>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
             <action method="addItem" ifconfig="path/to/config/status/enabled" condition="1"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script_one.js</name></action>
              <action method="addItem" ifconfig="path/to/config/status/enabled" condition="0"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script_two.js</name></action>
        </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
</layoutupdate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System configuration paths are split into three (3) parts: Section, group and field.  When reading the configuration, the path is constructed as: ***section***/**group**/*field*. There are two ways to find these pieces of information out:

### Inspecting the form and URL

> I find this to be the easiest **unless** I know what module the configuration I'm looking for comes from.  This is due to the fact that Magento 1.x has it's modules span multiple configuration areas and it's not always obvious which module goes to which configuration.

The easiest way I know of is to piece it together from the URL and the form, since usually I'm looking at the configuration as I'm adding a constraint to my layout.

If you look at the URL, you'll see it specifies the section like: `index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/design/`.  The important part is the **section/design** part.  This gives you the first part of the configuration path, the section: `design`

Next you would need to inspect the input field you want to reference.  For this example I'll use the demo store notice.  If you inspect this field, you'll see a name like this: `groups[head][fields][demonotice][value]`.  The important part here is before the value between the square brackets after `groups` and before `[fields]`.  This gives you the group of the configuration path: `head`

The last piece is the actual name of the configuration variable.  This will be the value between the square braces between the `[fields]` and `[value]` of the input field.  So for this example the value of the third and final element is: `demonotice`.

So the configuration path you would use is: `design/head/demonotice`

### Reading the `system.xml` file of the correct module

The alternative way to look this up is to open the `system.xml` of the corresponding module.  If you look in the `system.xml` file of the `Magento_Page` module you'll find the following XML:

```
<config>
  <sections>
    <design ...>
      <groups ...>
        <head ...>
          <fields ...>
            <demonotice ...>
            </demonotice>
          </fields>
        </head>
      </groups>
    </design>
  </sections>
</config>
```

So you'd need to find the configuration name you want, in this case `demonotice` and follow it up the tree to find the group name, in this case `head` and follow that up to the containing section name, in this case `design`.

So the resulting configuration path would be `design/head/demonotice`.

Answer (score 1):

[Brett](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/175385/46249) is completely right, but you can get config path easily from browsers inspector.

Just inspect the input field your are interesset in and you'll see something like this:

[image]

The `id` selector represent the full config path and if your config path contains underscores you can also take a look at `name` attribute.

### Limitations using `ifconfig`:

Unfortunately there are no `condition` parameters in layout files, `ifconfig` always returns a **boolean** value, see `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` ...

```
protected function _generateAction($node, $parent)
{
    if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
            return $this;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So you can only check if config is set to `0` or `1`. If you want to check the explicit value you have to create a helper method and adjust layout to something like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <item helper="module/helper/method"/>
    </action>
</reference>
```

---

<sup>Using free [Extended ifconfig](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extended-ifconfig.html) extension should allow you to add condition parameters.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is simpler, However as Brett did a well explained stuff I validate his answer but +1 ;) . You told that there is no condition in if config, assuming that i have in my field three values 1, 2, 3 so i can do some condition for exemple display my block if the value of my field is `3` `condition="3"`

Comment: Updated my answer.